# How to build url in model similar to template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have the following url in my template:

```
<a href="{% url titles order_item.title.id order_item.id 'assets' %}
         ?expanded=chaptering">Link
</a>
```

However, what I need to do is build the url **in my model**, so I can do something like this in my template:

```
{{ task.get_task_url }}
```

How would I get `{% url titles order_item.title.id order_item.id 'assets' %}` (for example, "/tasks/2/4/") in a model?

Can I use `redirect` and capture the url value or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `reverse` function does.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_task_url(order_item):
    return reverse('titles', args=(order_item.title.id, order_item.id, 'assets'))
```

Or kwargs, as appropriate.